# Using urllib2 for Python3

Tags: python, web

I wanted to use `urllib2` for python 3, but I don't think it's available in such name.

I use `urllib.request`, is there another way to use `urllib2?`

Comment: What do you mean by *another way*, do you want an alias for `urllib.request`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`urllib2` in Python 3 has been split into [several modules](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

> The `urllib2` module has been split across several modules in Python 3
>   named `urllib.request` and `urllib.error`. The `2to3` tool will
>   automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3.

[`urllib.request`](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html) is what you want to use for issuing HTTP requests.

Alternatively, the open source [Requests](http://python-requests.org) library provides a simpler and cleaner API for making HTTP requests in both Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

You should give [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) a try; it's available for Python 2.6—3.3. HTH.

Comment: agreed looking at the code using Requests from yr url against example using urllib2.request ~ https://gist.github.com/kennethreitz/973705

Answer (score 0):

> The `urllib2` module has been split across several modules in Python 3.0 
>       named `urllib.request` and `urllib.error`. The `2to3` tool will automatically 
>       adapt imports when converting your sources to 3